# Strange state change(UIControlState) of UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton, uicontrolstate

I got a strange `UIButton` result while understanding concept of `UIControlState`. Here is my simple code related to `UIButton`.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let normalBtn: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()

        button.frame = CGRect(x: 80, y: 200, width: 200, height: 100)

        button.setTitle("", for: .normal)
        button.setTitle("", for: .highlighted)
        button.setTitle("", for: .selected)
        button.setTitle("", for: .focused)

        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 50)

        return button
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(normalBtn)

        normalBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnSelected), for: .touchUpInside)

    }

    @objc func btnSelected() {
        print("highlight", normalBtn.isHighlighted)

        normalBtn.isSelected = !normalBtn.isSelected
    }

}
```

Here is my scenario about this code.

1. When I touch `normalBtn`, state of this button changes `normal` to
   `selected`.
2. When I touch `normalBtn` again, its state changes from
   `selected` to `normal`.
3. While these transitions, `highlighted` property also should be changed, when I touch `normalBtn`.

So my expectation of changing title is

1. ->  while touching -> (`normal` to `selected`)
2. ->  while touching -> (`selected` to `normal`)

But the result is,

1. ->  while touching -> (`normal` to `selected`)
2. -> (`selected` to `normal`)

I really don't know why. Any ideas about this question? Thanks.

Comment: From my knowledge, the highlighted state won't come from Selected to normal transition. Vice-versa works. Probably it's de-highlighting

Comment: @SivajeeBattina Then, is there a way to catch a point of de-highlighting like `normalBtn.isDeHighlighted`?

Comment: I expected this question. But there is no catching of de-highlighting.

Comment: @SivajeeBattina Inside of `btnSelected()`, `print("highlight", normalBtn.isHighlighted)` statement always prints `true`. Is this phenomenon is related to de-highlighting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding selected state combining with highlighted state.

Example:

```
button.setTitle("", for: UIControlState.selected.union(.highlighted))
```

Comment: as @sivajee said:" the highlighted state won't come from Selected to normal transition", so apple provides way to combine states together, just like in your case. and since highlight state comes before the selected/normal state, your case is satisfying. :)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! Now I understand how to use it.

Comment: my pleasure . :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative syntax to the accepted answer:

```
button.setTitle("", for: [.selected, .highlighted])
```